# So we are required to validate our forms using an external javascript document, my code will validate incorrectly any idea why?

Tags: javascript, forms

I've set the pattern for my javascript code and have error messages set up, but can't seemt o figure out how to force it to take ""@""."" as a format as it will accept single letters as valid for some reason

```
  function myFunction3() {
    var message, x, j;
    message = document.getElementById("message3");
    message.innerHTML = "";
    x = document.getElementById("Email").value;
    try {
    if (x == "") throw "Required Field";
    if (x =  /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/) throw "Valid";


      }
   catch(err) {
    message.innerHTML = err;

  }
  }
```

Comment: You're assigning a RegExp literal to `x` in the last `if` condition. Use [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) to test a string against to a RegExp. Also throwing an error after successed validation is weird.

Comment: i'm using the throw to test the validation but should i be not using a catch throw method then

Comment: Drop the `try ... catch` and peek the error messages from the console.

Comment: Like @Teemu said, use `let RegExp = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;` and `RegExp.test(x)`, also I would use `return` instead of `throw`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is setup a valid regex test. This looks something like this:

```
function myFunction3() {
    let message, x, j;
    let RegExp = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/; // Change this
    message = document.getElementById("message3");
    message.innerHTML = "";
    x = document.getElementById("Email").value;

    if (x === '') return 'Required Field';
    else if (RegExp.test(x)) return 'Valid';
    else return 'Value not valid';
}
```

I find using a regex tool like https://regexr.com/ is really helpful for getting the right validation. Since you only specify "accept single letters as valid for some reason" I'm not sure what exact expression you need, but if you elaborate I can help you create one :)

Comment: most of the codes seems to work except it doesn't return anything on the x=== ''

Comment: @JustineChen do a ‘console.log(x)’ to see what x is. == tests for the same value, === tests for the same value and type. So the ‘’ needs to be empty AND a string value

Comment: @JustineChen awesome! Glad I could help